# Pygame keeps crashing when I open it

Tags: python, crash, pygame

I've have this dodging aliens game and it's not working. I can get the front begin screen to open but then when I hit enter to start it crashes and freezes. I've tried running it from python.exe instead of just IDLE but in that case it just pops up then closes right down. A few errors popped up the first few times I tried to run it but now there are no errors indicating what might be wrong. It just stops responding. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *


def startGame():
    if event.type == K_ENTER:
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            sys.exit()
        return

def playerCollision():
    for a in aliens:
        if playerRect.colliderect(b['rect']):
            return True
    return False

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((750,750))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption('Dodge the Aliens')

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 55)

playerImage = pygame.image.load('')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
alienImage = pygame.image.load('')

drawText('Dodge the Aliens!', font, screen, (750 / 3), (750 / 3))
drawText('Press ENTER to start.', font, screen, (750 / 3) - 45, (750 / 3) +    65)
pygame.display.update()

topScore = 0
while True:
    aliens = []
    score = 0
    playerRect.topleft = (750 /2, 750 - 50)
    alienAdd = 0
    while True:
        score += 1
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: x -=3
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: x += 3
        if pressed[pygame.K_ESCAPE]: sys.exit()
    alienAdd += 1

    if alienAdd == addedaliens:
        aliendAdd = 0
        alienSize = random.randint(10, 40)
        newAlien = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, 750 - alienSize), 0 -alienSize, alienSize, alienSize), 'speed': random.randint(1, 8), 'surface':pygame.transform.scale(alienImage, (alienSize, alienSize)), }
        aliens.append(newAlien)
    for a in aliens[:]:
        if a['rect'].top > 750:
            aliens.remove(a)
    screen.fill(0,0,0)
    drawText('Score %s' % (score), font, screen, 10, 0)
    screen.blit(playerImage, playerRect)
    for a in aliens:
        screen.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])
    pygame.display.update()


    if playerCollision(playerRect, aliens):
        if score > topScore:
            topScore = score
        break

    clock.tick(60)

    drawText('Game Over!', font, screen, (750 / 3), ( 750 / 3))
    drawText('Press ENTER To Play Again.', font, screen, ( 750 / 3) - 80, (750 / 3) + 50)
    pygame.display.update()
    startGame()
```

Here's my new code after modifying it some
    import pygame, random, sys
    from pygame.locals import*
    alienimg = pygame.image.load('C:\Python27\alien.png')
    playerimg = pygame.image.load('C:\Python27\spaceship.png')

```
def playerCollision(): # a function for when the player hits an alien
    for a in aliens:
        if playerRect.colliderect(b['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def screenText(text, font, screen, x, y): #text display function
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, (255, 255, 255))
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x,y)
    screen.blit(textobj, textrect)

def main(): #this is the main function that starts the game

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((750,750))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    pygame.display.set_caption('Dodge the Aliens') 
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 55)


    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    aliens = []
    score = 0
    alienAdd = 0
    addedaliens = 0

    while True: #our while loop that actually runs the game



        for event in pygame.event.get(): #key controls
            if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: 
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: 
                playerRect.x -= 3

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerRect.x += 3


          playerImage = pygame.image.load('C:\\Python27\\spaceship.png').convert() # the player images
        playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
        playerRect.topleft = (750 /2, 750 - 50)
        alienImage = pygame.image.load('C:\\Python27\\alien.png').convert() #alien images   

        alienAdd += 1

        pygame.display.update()

        if alienAdd == addedaliens: # randomly adding aliens of different sizes and speeds
            aliendAdd = 0
            alienSize = random.randint(10, 40)
            newAlien = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, 750 - alienSize), 0 -alienSize, alienSize, alienSize), 'speed': random.randint(1, 8), 'surface':pygame.transform.scale(alienImage, (alienSize, alienSize)), }
            aliens.append(newAlien)
        for a in aliens[:]:
            if a['rect'].top > 750:
                aliens.remove(a) #removes the aliens when they get to the bottom of the screen

        screen.blit(screen, (0,0))
        screenText('Score %s' % (score), font, screen, 10, 0)
        screen.blit(playerImage, playerRect)
        for a in aliens:
            screen.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])
        pygame.display.flip()


        if playerCollision(playerRect, aliens):
            if score > topScore:
                topScore = score
            break


        clock.tick(60)

        screenText('Game Over!', font, screen, (750 / 6), ( 750 / 6))
        screenText('Press ENTER To Play Again.', font, screen, ( 750 / 6) - 80, (750 / 6) + 50)
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I still see several issues with your code and I think you're trying to do too much at once for the very beginning. Try to keep it as simple as possible. Try creating a display and draw some image:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((750, 750))
img = pygame.image.load("""C:\\Game Dev\\alien.png""")
display.blit(img, (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

You'll have to adjust the img path of course. Running this you should either get an explicit Error (which you should then post in another thread) or see your img on the screen. BUT the program will not respond as there's no event handling and no main loop at all.

To avoid this, you could introduce a main loop like:

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()

RESOLUTION = (750, 750)
FPS = 60

display = pygame.display.set_mode(RESOLUTION)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
img = pygame.image.load("""C:\\Game Dev\\alien.png""")

while True:  # <--- game loop

    # check quit program
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    # clear the screen
    display.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # draw the image
    display.blit(img, (0, 0))
    # update the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    # tick the clock
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

This should result in a program that displays the same img over and over, and it can be quit properly using the mouse. But still it's like a script, and if someone imported this, it would execute immediately, which is not what we want. So let's fix that as well and wrap it all up in a main function like this:

```
import sys
import pygame

#defining some constants
RESOLUTION = (750, 750)
FPS = 60

def main(): # <--- program starts here

    # setting things up
    pygame.init()
    display = pygame.display.set_mode(RESOLUTION)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    img = pygame.image.load("""C:\\Game Dev\\alien.png""")

    while True:  # <--- game loop

        # check quit program
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        # clear the screen
        display.fill((0, 0, 0))
        # draw the image
        display.blit(img, (0, 0))
        # update the screen
        pygame.display.flip()
        # tick the clock
        clock.tick(FPS)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The 'if **name** == "**main**":' ensures that the program does not execute when it's imported.

I hope this helps. And remember: Don't try too much all at once. Take small steps, one after another, and try to keep the control over your program. If needed, you can even put a print statement after every single line of code to exactly let you know what your program does and in what order.

Comment: Can I kindly suggest you give an example of your suggestion for @ndoll?

Comment: Thank you. I'm not the best at python yet but I'm trying to learn. So just to clarify, the while loop should be inside my main function?

Comment: I turned the first while loop into a main function but I'm still having the same problem :(